# JAVA: How to ensure 1 method has completed before invoking the next?

Tags: java, android, database, methods

activity1:

```
public void firstMethod(){

//has code intiates another activity and method (thirdMethod) where an id is retrieved

}
```

acitivity2:

```
public void thirdMethod(){  

//has code that does query for an id and stores it as a variable 

}
```

activity 1:

```
public void secondMethod(){

//has code that displays the variable from thirdMethod

}
```

What I'm trying to do is set variables for database call (activity1), retrieve an id/execute database call (activity2), store result as a variable (activity2) and then display in the original activity (activity 1)

Problem is: It goes firstMethod, secondMethod, thirdMethod rather than firstMethod, thirdMethod, secondMethod so the variable is null.

It seems to complete all activity 1 methods before the actual database call in activity 2.

**What do I need to do to ensure first and third methods are done before displaying the variable?**

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with following steps:

1. Call method 1 in Activity1
2. Launch Activity2 with `startActivityForResult` and call method 3 there
3. In `OnActivityResult` call method 2 in Activity1

Then you get method 1, 3 and 2 called in correct sequence.